# Ideas for a project in Data Structures and Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, data-structure

I have a project to do on Data Structures & Machine Learning.

I admit that my background on this subject is not the greatest but I love challenges.

The idea of the project would be to explore articles on this subject.

The problem I encounter is that I don't know how to "search for articles" and therefore I can't find material on which I should base my project.

Could you tell me places / sources to "get" articles on this topic or even recommend me some interesting articles?

Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: Data structures and machine learning are two gigantic fields. I'd suggesting learning about them first before doing any project, because it's clear to me that you currently don't know much about either. Can't do a project without knowing what they are about.

Comment: Once you pick a particular subdomain to write an exposition on, you can use tools like sci-direct, google scholar, and various others to find articles. However, I have to caution you: do not go searching through these databases without knowing what you are looking for (which you do not). It's the wild west out there and it really only is useful when you are searching for a specific idea.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice @DonThousand

Answer (score 1):

After you decide what actually you are going to do your project on, you could look at Harvard Dataverse. They have replication data for articles, i.e. the datasets that were used and analyzed in the writing of the articles. The articles aren’t always on the website, so you might need to google them after getting the data. Also, the data might need some preprocessing and the level of difficulty of replicating a study’s results may vary.

Kaggle is another popular option. I’ve not used this but it seems like they have hosted data analysis competitions before. In general it seems like this is lower quality but lays out the steps for you. The one time I read a Kaggle article it was pretty simple, but I’m not sure all Kaggle articles are like that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: No probs! Example project could be fitting a model to some data. E.g. covid data.